# Using Mock classes with TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P in gmock and gtest C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

Below is an example illustrating my problem. I have some [parametrized TYPED_TESTS](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#type-parameterized-tests) which run on all classes derived from a base class and are registered as follows.

```
REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(FooSharedTest, Test1, Test2, Test3)
```

I instantiate the tests for the derived class `Bar` which takes in another class `ClassA` argument as follows. I am mocking the `ClassA` for testing.

```
std::shared_ptr<MockClassA> mockA = std::make_shared<MockClassA>();

template <> std::shared_ptr<Foo> CreateFoo<Bar>()
{
    return std::make_shared<Bar>(mockA);
}

INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(BarTest, FooSharedTest, Bar);

}
```

Now I want to return different values from the `MockClassA` class's functions by doing

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mockA, Func()).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(true));
```

I can't put this `EXPECT_CALL` in the `TYPED_TEST_P` of `FooSharedTest` because the `mockA` is not is scope and shouldn't be either. Then how do I pass different expectations for mocked class into the TYPED_TESTs. I am doing it currently by returning a single value of `true` from the `MockClassA` but that defeats the purpose since for every return value I will have to write another Mock class.

To conclude, the question is how do I used `EXPECT_CALL` within derived class's mocked objects with `TYPED_TEST_P`?

Comment: Hi, can you share whole test? I'm having a hard time understanding the question/problem here. Regarding returning `true` from `Func()` mock call - sems OK, you should have one test that return true and another that return false to control the test flow